# How to implement a function to use out of its local scope?

Tags: c, opengl

I'm working with images in C and OpenGL to show them in a window. I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct imagemRGB ImagemRGB;
struct imageRGB {
    int  width;        
    int height;        
    PixelRGB **pixel;
};
```

Where `**pixel` is a matrix that represent each pixel and its color in the image. PixelRGB is a struct like this:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;

typedef Byte Boolean;

/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* pixel True Color */
/* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Color#True_color_.2824-bit.29 */
typedef struct pixelRGB PixelRGB;
struct pixelRGB {
  Byte    red;         /* valor entre 0 e 255 */
  Byte    green;       /* valor entre 0 e 255 */
  Byte    blue;        /* valor entre 0 e 255*/
  Boolean visited;    /* TRUE ou FALSE */ 
};
```

I have a function signature which is:

```
void copyImageRGB (ImageRGB *target, ImageRGB *origin);
```

This function is supposed to copy the image structure (`width`, `height` and each `pixel`) to the `target` so I can have the OriginalImage stored since the beginning;

I'm implementing it with this code:

```
copyImageRGB (ImageRGB *target, ImageRGB *origin)
{
int i, j;

target->width = origin->width;
target->height = origin->height;
for(i = 0; i < origin->height; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < origin->width; j++)
  {
    target->pixel[i][j].red = origin->pixel[i][j].red;
    target->pixel[i][j].blue = origin->pixel[i][j].blue;
    target->pixel[i][j].green = origin->pixel[i][j].green;
  }
}
```

Bu I'm not sure it will work as expected in my `main` because its arguments are local variables. Am I right? How do I implement this function so that I can do: `copyImageRGB(target, originalImage);` in my `main`?

Comment: Why are you using `**pixel`?

Comment: **pixel is a matrix. Later on, image->pixel[30][40] represents the pixel in 30x40 location

Comment: @RodrigoAlves: Not it's not a matrix. It's a pointer to a pointer. Matrices, vectors, image data, etc. are usually represented by a flat array for efficiency reasons. The type to address that would be a single pointer. (Pointers to pointers introduce one additional indirection (bad) and the memory will likely not be allocated contiguously (worse)). You address a flat array with `image->pixels[y*image->width + x];`. I know that chaining up index operators is tempting to do in C/C++, but if you know what actually happens, you don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your local variables are still alive when you call `copyImageRGB` function, your code will work (compile), however, you need to allocate `pixel` field, in the target, as it is just a pointer to a pointer. And you could do it inside `main`, but it could be a better option to allocate it inside `copyImageRGB`:

```
copyImageRGB (ImageRGB *target, ImageRGB *origin)
{
int i, j;
target->pixel = malloc(sizeof(PixelRGB) * origin->height * origin->width);
target->width = origin->width;
target->height = origin->height;
for(i = 0; i < origin->height; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < origin->width; j++)
  {
    target->pixel[i][j].red = origin->pixel[i][j].red;
    target->pixel[i][j].blue = origin->pixel[i][j].blue;
    target->pixel[i][j].green = origin->pixel[i][j].green;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to free your pixel!

```
int main()
{
    ImageRGB src = /* Get is somehow */;
    ImageRGB target;

    copyImageRGB(&target, &src);
    free(src->pixel);
    free(target->pixel);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you could use pointers as local variables, but then you need to make sure you allocate `target` structure:

```
int main()
{
    ImageRGB *src = /* Get it somehow */;
    ImageRGB *target = malloc(sizeof(ImageRGB));

    copyImageRGB(target, src);

    // Don't forget to free!
    free(src->pixel);
    free(src);
    free(target->pixel);
    free(target);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what your problem is, but the function should work fine, as long as both the parameters are pointers to valid objects. You do need to allocate memory for the pixel matrix in copyImageRGB(). For, example, something like following should work.

```
copyImageRGB (ImageRGB *target, ImageRGB *origin)
{
int i, j;

target->width = origin->width;
target->height = origin->height;
target->pixel = (PixelRGB**)malloc(sizeof(PixelRGB[origin->height][origin->width])); // <------ NOTE memory allocation
for(i = 0; i < origin->height; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < origin->width; j++)
  {
    target->pixel[i][j].red = origin->pixel[i][j].red;
    target->pixel[i][j].blue = origin->pixel[i][j].blue;
    target->pixel[i][j].green = origin->pixel[i][j].green;
  }
}


int main() {
    ImageRGB originalImage;

    // initialize originalImage somehow

    ImageRGB target;

    copyImageRGB(&target, &originalImage);
}
```